# Can we call two functions in single function in appscript calling?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to call another function in a fuction which is returning a value as shownn below. Please let me know if my method is correct :

```
function runnCode(){
      var fcolor = document.getElementById("color-1-hex").value;
      var bgcolor = document.getElementById("color-2-hex").value;
    

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ratio => {
        
        //document.getElementById("#result").innerHTML = result;
        var n = 1/ratio;
        var actualRatio = n.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("ratio").innerHTML = actualRatio + ":1";
        document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
        document.getElementById("aa-large").className   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : "fail";
        document.getElementById("aaa-normal").className = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : "fail";
        document.getElementById("aaa-large").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
        document.getElementById("ratioContainer").className   = ratio > 0.22222 ? "" : "pass";

        // document.getElementById("aa-normal"). = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
         const demo = document.getElementById("sample-text");
          demo.style.color = fcolor;
          demo.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;

        const totalWrong = document.querySelectorAll(".fail").length;
        let mouth = document.getElementById("mouth");
        let smile = document.getElementById("smile");
        switch(totalWrong) {
      case 0:
        mouth = mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z") ;
        smile = smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z");
        
        break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,141 C 140,141 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,141 125,141 Z");
        
        break;
      case 3: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  140,143  125,143  110,143 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,138 C 140,138 143.5,132 143.5,132 143.5,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,138 125,138 Z");
        break;
      case 4: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  134,142  125,142  116,142 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,135 C 140,135 143,132 143,132 143,135 125,136 125,136 125,136 106.5,135 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,135 125,135 Z");
        
       break;
    }
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( suggestedColor {
             document.getElementById("aa-normal").innerHTML  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
             document.getElementById("aa-large").innerHTML   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : suggestedColor;
             document.getElementById("aaa-normal").innerHTML = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : suggestedColor;
             document.getElementById("aaa-large").innerHTML  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
       }).hexx(fcolor, bgcolor);
         

      document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = "fail";
         console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#aa-normal").className.=);
      }).calculateRatio(fcolor,bgcolor);
    
      
}
```

Want to call two functions , both of them returning some value. Kindly let me knnow the correct way of calling two functions in google appscript

Comment: Yes you can nest them inside of the withSuccessHandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( suggestedColor {` is required to be modified like `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(suggestedColor => {`.
- In this case, I think that there are 2 directions for achieving your goal.

  1. At Google Apps Script side, the functions of `calculateRatio` and `hexx` are merged and the values of `ratio` and `suggestedColor` are returned. In this case, `google.script.run` is used one time.
  2. At Javascript side, the values of `ratio` and `suggestedColor` are retrieved using 2 `google.script.run` by returned Promise. By this, the readability of script might be a bit high.

In your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the functions of `calculateRatio` and `hexx` of your Google Apps Script. So, in this answer, I would like to propose above 2nd direction.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

```
const calculateRatio = (fcolor, bgcolor) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).withFailureHandler(reject).calculateRatio(fcolor, bgcolor));
const hexx = (fcolor, bgcolor) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).withFailureHandler(reject).hexx(fcolor, bgcolor));

async function runnCode() {
  const fcolor = document.getElementById("color-1-hex").value;
  const bgcolor = document.getElementById("color-2-hex").value;
  const ratio = await calculateRatio(fcolor, bgcolor).catch(err => console.log(err));
  const suggestedColor = await hexx(fcolor, bgcolor).catch(err => console.log(err));

  var n = 1/ratio;
  var actualRatio = n.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ratio").innerHTML = actualRatio + ":1";
  document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("aa-large").className   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("aaa-normal").className = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("aaa-large").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("ratioContainer").className   = ratio > 0.22222 ? "" : "pass";
  const demo = document.getElementById("sample-text");
  demo.style.color = fcolor;
  demo.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
  const totalWrong = document.querySelectorAll(".fail").length;
  let mouth = document.getElementById("mouth");
  let smile = document.getElementById("smile");
  switch(totalWrong) {
    case 0:
      mouth = mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z") ;
      smile = smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z");
      break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
      mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,141 C 140,141 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,141 125,141 Z");
      break;
    case 3: 
      mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  140,143  125,143  110,143 109,138 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,138 C 140,138 143.5,132 143.5,132 143.5,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,138 125,138 Z");
      break;
    case 4: 
      mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  134,142  125,142  116,142 109,138 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,135 C 140,135 143,132 143,132 143,135 125,136 125,136 125,136 106.5,135 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,135 125,135 Z");
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("aa-normal").innerHTML  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
  document.getElementById("aa-large").innerHTML   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : suggestedColor;
  document.getElementById("aaa-normal").innerHTML = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : suggestedColor;
  document.getElementById("aaa-large").innerHTML  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;

  document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = "fail";
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#aa-normal").className.=);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, your Google Apps Script is modified.

Please add the following script to Google Apps Script. By this, the values of `ratio` and `suggestedColor` are retrieved by one call.

```
const sample = (fcolor, bgcolor) => [calculateRatio(fcolor, bgcolor), hexx(fcolor, bgcolor)];
```

And, please modify your Javascript as follows.

```
function runnCode(){
  var fcolor = document.getElementById("color-1-hex").value;
  var bgcolor = document.getElementById("color-2-hex").value;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(([ratio, suggestedColor]) => {
    var n = 1/ratio;
    var actualRatio = n.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("ratio").innerHTML = actualRatio + ":1";
    document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
    document.getElementById("aa-large").className   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : "fail";
    document.getElementById("aaa-normal").className = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : "fail";
    document.getElementById("aaa-large").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
    document.getElementById("ratioContainer").className   = ratio > 0.22222 ? "" : "pass";
    const demo = document.getElementById("sample-text");
    demo.style.color = fcolor;
    demo.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
    const totalWrong = document.querySelectorAll(".fail").length;
    let mouth = document.getElementById("mouth");
    let smile = document.getElementById("smile");
    switch(totalWrong) {
      case 0:
        mouth = mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z") ;
        smile = smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z");
        break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,141 C 140,141 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,141 125,141 Z");
        break;
      case 3: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  140,143  125,143  110,143 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,138 C 140,138 143.5,132 143.5,132 143.5,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,138 125,138 Z");
        break;
      case 4: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  134,142  125,142  116,142 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,135 C 140,135 143,132 143,132 143,135 125,136 125,136 125,136 106.5,135 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,135 125,135 Z");
        break;
    }
    document.getElementById("aa-normal").innerHTML  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
    document.getElementById("aa-large").innerHTML   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : suggestedColor;
    document.getElementById("aaa-normal").innerHTML = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : suggestedColor;
    document.getElementById("aaa-large").innerHTML  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;

    document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = "fail";
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#aa-normal").className.=);
  }).sample(fcolor,bgcolor);
}
```

#### References:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thankyou @Tanaike, your solution always work. Please let me know how i can change the content of css . Like I have stylesheet : #boxes > div.fail::before {
   content: "✓ color";
}
#boxes > div.fail {
  background: #d32;
}

#boxes > div.fail::after {
  content: "✕ Fail";
} Please let me know how i can pass the value of "suggestedColor" in the content of before div like  #boxes > div.fail::before {
   content: "✓ suggestedColor";
}

Comment: @kanu priya By the way, I added one more modification pattern. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestionn @Tanaike . Please help me in resolving https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840118/how-can-i-change-css-content-with-attr-and-appscript

Comment: Yeah I have seen the modification part. Thanks for sharing the same. I will use it in another part of my code :)

Comment: @kanu priya Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227673/discussion-between-kanu-priya-and-tanaike).