# How can I change css content with attr and appscript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function which is returing a value "Suggested color" , however I want to put that value as content in stylsheet with class

```
#boxes > div.fail::before {
  content : attr(data-content);
}
```

whereas my appscript is shown as below which is returning value "suggested color"
I want that value to be printed in

```
div.fail::before{content : }
```

dynamically.
So my appscript function is

```
 
const calculateRatio = (fcolor, bgcolor) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).withFailureHandler(reject).calculateRatio(fcolor, bgcolor));
const hexx = (fcolor, bgcolor) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resolve).withFailureHandler(reject).hexx(fcolor, bgcolor));
async function runnCode() {
  const fcolor = document.getElementById("color-1-hex").value;
  const bgcolor = document.getElementById("color-2-hex").value;
  const ratio = await calculateRatio(fcolor, bgcolor).catch(err => console.log(err));
  const suggestedColor = await hexx(fcolor, bgcolor).catch(err => console.log(err));

  var n = 1/ratio;
  var actualRatio = n.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ratio").innerHTML = actualRatio + ":1";
  document.getElementById("aa-normal").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("aa-large").className   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("aaa-normal").className = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("aaa-large").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
  document.getElementById("ratioContainer").className   = ratio > 0.22222 ? "" : "pass";
  const demo = document.getElementById("sample-text");
  demo.style.color = fcolor;
  demo.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
  const totalWrong = document.querySelectorAll(".fail").length;
  let mouth = document.getElementById("mouth");
  let smile = document.getElementById("smile");
  switch(totalWrong) {
    case 0:
      mouth = mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z") ;
      smile = smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z");
      break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
      mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,141 C 140,141 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,141 125,141 Z");
      break;
    case 3: 
      mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  140,143  125,143  110,143 109,138 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,138 C 140,138 143.5,132 143.5,132 143.5,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,138 125,138 Z");
      break;
    case 4: 
      mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  134,142  125,142  116,142 109,138 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,135 C 140,135 143,132 143,132 143,135 125,136 125,136 125,136 106.5,135 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,135 125,135 Z");
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("aa-normal").attr('data-content')  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
  document.getElementById("aa-large").attr("data-content")   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : fail;
  document.getElementById("aaa-normal").attr('data-content') = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : fail;
  document.getElementById("aaa-large").attr('data-content')  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : fail;

  
}
```

Kindly suggest how to modify below line so as to print the value of suggestedColor in conntent of div.fail::before

```
document.getElementById("aa-normal").attr('data-content')  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
```

Html is as follows

```
 <div id="boxes">
    <div id="aa-large">
      <span>Large Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AA</span>
    </div>
    <div id="aa-normal" data-content="">
      <span>Normal Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AA</span>
    </div>
    <div id="aaa-large" data-content="">
      <span>Large Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AAA</span>
    </div>
    <div id="aaa-normal" data-content="">
      <span>Normal Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AAA</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

stylesheet >>

```
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

#boxes > div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: #081;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

#boxes > div::after {
  content: "✓ Pass";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#boxes > div::before {
  
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -28px;
}
#boxes > div.fail::before {
  content : attr(data-content);
   /* content: "✓ ";  */
}
#boxes > div.fail {
  background: #d32;
}

#boxes > div.fail::after {
  content: "✕ Fail";
}

#boxes > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#boxes span:first-child {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, `attr()` of `document.getElementById("aa-normal").attr('data-content')  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;` might not be correct. In this case, how about modifying as follows.

#### From:

```
document.getElementById("aa-normal").attr('data-content')  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor;
```

#### To:

```
document.getElementById("aa-normal").setAttribute('data-content', ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColor);
```

#### Reference:

- [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: Thankyou it is working however when I do the same code for another element output is not coming. Output is working for the first one only and not for the other 3.      document.getElementById("aa-normal").setAttribute("data-content",  ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : suggestedColorAAnormal);
  document.getElementById("aa-large").setAttribute("data-content", ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : suggestedColorAALarge); For second one it is not giving output.

Comment: @kanu priya Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, I cannot understand about it. Because I cannot see the vision of your current script from your replying. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your new issue, can you post it as new question by including more information? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?